# Create dynamic tag with text and cross sign

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, user-interface

I want to create multiple tag with text and cross sign.
I can enter text in textField and on click add button it will make tag and display in tag section. And also I can remove tag from tag section.

Please give me idea how I can create UI for this. What will be best way to implement this. For reference please check image [URL.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00cuO.jpg)

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tltagscontrol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using UICollectionView. [See this](https://codentrick.com/create-a-tag-flow-layout-with-uicollectionview/) . You can customize according to your need. You can get a lot of library for this type of control. Or you can make your own.